# Why there is no language server protocol for the `emacs-lisp` language?

Tags: emacs, language-server-protocol

Why there is no language server protocol for the `emacs-lisp` language?
For example, the `lsp-mode` package for Emacs contains support for many languages with their respecting language servers. But no `emacs-lisp`.

Why is that so?

The same goes for the `eglot` package too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there is no language server available for a given language, that is because no one has been sufficiently motivated to go to the effort of writing one.

I'm sure if anyone wants this badly enough, they'll write one; but very few people who *don't use Emacs* are likely to be interested in writing a language server which is of almost no benefit to non-Emacs users; and for people who *do* use Emacs, Emacs has always provided a pretty robust development environment for writing Emacs Lisp, and I imagine most people feel that's already good enough.

Also bear in mind that the development environment "Emacs" and the normal runtime environment for the programming language "Emacs Lisp" are *the same program*.  Which is unusual.  So Emacs isn't reliant upon any external program like a language server to tell it things about the language.

I do recall this topic coming up in the [development lists](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-10/msg00715.html), and some people felt that the primary benefit to an elisp language server would be to people using editors *other* than Emacs and that efforts would be better directed at improvements to Emacs.  There wasn't a general agreement on that, but nevertheless it probably reduces the pool of people who might feel the need to work on such a project in the first place.

Comment: I understand what you are saying is like this: "Emacs itself has such great features and support and not what for the Elisp language that you don't really need an LSP". Am I correct? If yes, then here is my counterargument: I tried googling for the simplest things to do on an Elisp buffer and could not find anything. How do you do formatting (not indenting)? Go to definition? Hover? I must be using the wrong keywords for my google searches.

Comment: Format manually.  `find-function` and `find-variable` (or `xref-find-definitions`).  I don't know what you want from "hover".  I'm sure you won't find equivalents for all LSP features, but I think that such absences are not necessarily going to prompt anyone to write a language server.  (I believe LSP is less than a decade old, and people have been happily writing Emacs Lisp for three decades more than that.)

Comment: Of course someone may already be working on one for all I know -- there's no technical reason why one couldn't be written, so all it takes is someone who wants it badly enough to do it.  I'm not currently aware of such a project, though, and I'm mostly just trying to point out why it might not be a high priority for many people.

Comment: "I'm sure you won't find equivalents for all LSP features" - I must say it bothers me greatly. All those LSP feature are making the life of the developer much easier. "Format manually" - I dont want to do it manually, we have computers for that :-) It truly does pick my interest why there is no LSP like facilities for Elisp.

Comment: Please edit your answer with examples of "Emacs has always provided a pretty robust development environment for writing Emacs Lisp". Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know what it is that you want, sorry, and I'm not going to try to enumerate all the editing features in Emacs.

Comment: "I don't know what it is that you want, sorry, and I'm not going to try to enumerate all the editing features in Emacs." - Here are a few examples of what an LSP server provides: go to definition, hover, parameters, formatting. UPDATE: Aaaand now the light bulb hit me! I managed to find the proper google search keyword to replicate all the functionality of an LSP using vanilla Emacs. For example: "emacs elisp go to definition" and/or "emacs elisp hover" and etc.

Comment: One more [argument against Elisp LS](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-10/msg00720.html): "pay the price of
serializing from/to JSON, RPC, and having an inferior process running all the time when the introspection capabilities of Emacs can provide the same capabilities".